# Glassfish 4.1 - what are the load balancing fields in web-admin for?

Tags: load-balancing, glassfish-4

If you search for load balancing possibilities of the glassfish, you can find the articles and tutorials about using mod_jk/mod_proxy - an external solution.

But the web-admin of the glassfish has in several places (instances etc.) the fields to setup loadbalancing - like LB weight - what are these fields for?
In Glassfish 3.* it was possible to use the load balancing plugin - but now? These fields seem to be useless - or i miss some other features of these fields?